# Detecting or Preventing Calls to a Method from a Specific Method

Tags: java

I am writing a JUnit test for code submitted to a competition. The rules of the competition require that certain methods not be called from other methods. (I unfortunately can not change the rules.)

The contestants are all implementing an interface we supplied which includes an `add(K key, V value)` method and a `delete(K key)` method. We need to test that entries do not implement delete by adding every other element to a new object and return that object.

We are also trying to avoid adding dependencies outside of the Java core since we are using a lot of automated tools (like the [Marmoset Project](http://marmoset.cs.umd.edu/index.shtml)) to test the hundreds of submissions.

I read through the documentation for Java Reflection and Instrumentation and nothing jumped out at me.

We are using Java 8 if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution in the end. It looks like in the original question, I did not mention that this was a binary tree, so the compareTo function would be used constantly.

I created an Exception we could throw in our test framework and then detect.

```java
public static class NotAllowedException extends RuntimeException
```

I created a new type that would have a flag that could be set to true by the testing framework before calling delete.

```java
/**
 * This class uses reflection to check whether {@link compareTo()} is being
 * called inside the add method after the test decides it is done with the
 * add method.
 * It will throw a {@link NotAllowedException}.
 *
 * @author yakatz <email@domain.com>
 */
private class MyIntWrapper {
    private boolean doneAdding = false;

    public void doneAdding() {
        this.doneAdding(true);
    }

    public void doneAdding(boolean b) {
        this.doneAdding = b;
    }

    private class MyInteger implements Comparable<MyInteger> {

        private Integer value;

        public MyInteger(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(MyInteger o) {
            if (MyIntWrapper.this.doneAdding) {
                StackTraceElement[] causes = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
                for (StackTraceElement cause : causes) {
                    if (cause.getClassName().equals("tree.Node") && cause.getMethodName().equals("add")) {
                        throw new NotAllowedException();
                    }
                }
            }
            return this.value.compareTo(o.value);
        }
    }
}
```

I can then use the class in tests like this:

```java
MyIntWrapper mir = new MyIntWrapper();
Tree<MyIntWrapper.MyInteger, String> tree = new Tree();
// Add stuff to the tree
mir.doneAdding();

MyIntWrapper.MyInteger mi = mir.new MyInteger(1);
tree = tree.delete(mi); // Will throw NotAllowedException if add() is called
```

Answer (score 0):

AspectJ compile time weaving will probably be your best bet.

You will need to recompile the code with aspectj compiler and add advice to intercept the call.

If you give me more details I can show some example code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a mocking library, and to use a "spy" test object. Using [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito) it might look something like this.

eg.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class Test {

    @Spy 
    ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteNeverCalled() {
        // given
        String key = randomString();
        String value = randomString();

        // when
        classUnderTest.add(key, value)

        // then
        verify(classUnderTest, never()).delete(any());
    }

}
```